# Grails Query Result return

Tags: sql, object, grails

This is mu Controller Query;

```
      Sql sqlStatement = new Sql(dataSource)
    def sqlString = ("SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(doc_hdr_0.date_created,'%D %M %Y') AS 'X', Count(DATE_FORMAT(doc_hdr_0.date_created,'%D %M %Y')) AS 'Y'\n" +
            "FROM doccon.doc_hdr doc_hdr_0\n" +
            "GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(doc_hdr_0.date_created,'%D %M %Y')")

    def returnList = []
    sqlStatement.eachRow(sqlString){
        returnList << it.toRowResult()
    }
    sqlStatement.close()
    [returnList:returnList]
```

Result
    [{X=12th September 2015, Y=3}, {X=14th September 2015, Y=1}, {X=15th September 2015, Y=2}, {X=16th September 2015, Y=16}, {X=8th September 2015, Y=2}] THIS WHAT I WANT WITHOUT = INSTED :

I want to change the = sign to : how can I do that?

when I change [returnList:returnList] to render returnList

the result is 
[['X':'12th September 2015', 'Y':3], ['X':'14th September 2015', 'Y':1], ['X':'15th September 2015', 'Y':2], ['X':'16th September 2015', 'Y':16], ['X':'8th September 2015', 'Y':2]]
now the result is [[k,v]] strange

Comment: What do you mean you want? Are you trying to return this of a gsp javascript function?

Comment: Yes I am trying to pass the result to JavaScript function.  I am using a JavaScript charts to display the result

Comment: This works <g:applyCodec encodeAs="none">
            var data = ${returnLists};
        </g:applyCodec>